# Microcontroller like the esp8266 with more gpio

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, gpio, esp8266

I am looking for a microcontroller similar to the ESP8266, which has the following features:

1/ 36 dedicated gpio

2/ I2S for driving audio

3/ I2C for driving screens

4/ SPI

5/ WiFi Station and AP modes

6/ Any language will do

I want at least 36 pins gpio, all of which would be used and then additional pins for the other needs such is I2C, I2S SPI.

Spec wise it could be a bit more powerful than the esp8266, and need not be Arduino compatible, I just want it to be good value. Advice from enthusiasts with more experience than me would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic for this site, but since the answer is so glaringly obvious I can't help myself. ESP32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually downvote shopping questions, but this one sounds general enough that it could benefit others.

It sounds like you want the ESP8266's bigger brother, the [ESP32](https://esp32.com). It has more I/O, is faster (and comes in dual-core variants) and more/better peripherals than its little brother.

However, if all you need is extra digital I/O, take a look at the [many](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PCAL9535A.pdf) [port](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tca9534a.pdf) [expanders](http://www.microchip.com/mymicrochip/filehandler.aspx?ddocname=en021920) available. Just go to [Digi-Key](http://digi-key.com), [Mouser](http://mouser.com), [TME](http://tme.eu) or your favourite sourcing sites and start using their searches. Many port expanders operate over I2C, can support multiple expanders on a single bus, and come with interrupt capability (so the host MCU doesn't have to continuously poll the slow I2C bus for status changes).